# Почему пределы чисел именно такие?

Tags: история

Почему почти во всех языках программирования данные ограниченны именно степенью двойки?

```
char (-127, 127) or (0, 255)
127 = (2^7) - 1 ; 255 = (2^8) - 1
```

и вопрос еще почему тут на 1 меньше, а не ровно 128 и 256?

```
int (-2147483648, 2147483647)
-2147483648 = -(2^31) ; 2147483647 = (2^31) - 1
```

и опять же почему тут на 1 меньше? а в отрицательном значении все нормально.

почему лимит именно такой, причем я посмотрел в других языках программирования также: везде используется степень двойки. но почему именно двойки а не тройки, не четверки?
почему нельзя было сделать лимит не таким а например вот таким:

```
int (-1000000000, 1000000000)
```

а для `char` тогда:

```
char (300, 300) или char (1000, 1000)
```

даже в майнкрафте ограничение по высоте именно в 256 блоков!
почти везде создают буфер из 255 или 256 элементов, особенно когда это касается текста

```
char buf[255]
```

так все же почему так сложилось?

Comment: даже в данных такая же ситуация
1 байт = 8 бит
1 кбайт = 1024 байт
итд

Comment: Читайте о двоичной сстеме счисления, именно она - основа общения с компьютером. Да/нет, истина/ложь, 1/0 - четкие пороги наличия или отсутствия сигнала. А то, что не докладывают 1 до 256 - так враки все это, докладывают - счет начинается с 0. Пример: 0000 (в двоичной)  = 0 (в 10-тичной), 0001=1, 0011=1+2=3, 1111=1+2+4+8=15. Почему так? 2 в степени N

Comment: `почему тут на 1 меньше, а не ровно 128 и 256?` - потому что от 1 до 255 - это 255 возможных значений и еще ноль - итого 256. Аналогично от -128 до 127 (такой диапазон signed char) - это 128 значений меньше нуля, 127 значений больше нуля и сам ноль - итого 256.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Имеется теорема Шеннона, согласно которой, для наиболее оптимального кодирования подходит система счисления по основанию `e=2.71....`. Следовательно, оптимальными будут системы по основанию 2 и 3. Для системы счисления по основанию 2 в электротехнике существует вполне очевидная реализация - "напряжение есть - 1", "напряжения нет - 0".

Реализация же троичной системы "в железе" оказывается более затратной, поэтому выбрали двоичный подход. Кстати, ЭНИАК работал и вовсе по основанию 10.

Теперь о числе 255. Это максимальное целое значение, которое можно записать в 8 бит, то есть, в современный байт. Байт в 8 бит появился не сразу - были и 6 битные машины, и 5,5 (пять-с-половиной. Что? Да!) битные.

Но оказалось, что в 4+4 бита удобно помещать двухзначное целое число, которое представляет фрагмент даты. В первые 4 бита - первую цифру, во вторые 4 - вторую цифру. Кроме того, в 255 кодов можно было поместить весь английский алфавит, цифры, спец-символы, и какой-то национальный алфавит. То есть, 8 бит дают оптимальный баланс между стоимостью производства электроники в середине 20 века и удобством использования.

Все остальные размеры, это случаи с кратными байту величинами - 2^16, 2^32 и далее.

Для работы с отрицательными числами используется, в частности, дополнительный код - чтобы записать отрицательное число, нужно перевернуть биты соответствующего положительного числа и прибавить 1. Именно сюда и девается недостающая единичка.

Нужно это для того, чтобы 0 представлялся однозначно, иначе бы `00000000 == 11111111` в дополнительном коде, то есть, существовало бы два нуля.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, но почему тогда именно 2^31 степени является пределом, а не 2^30 и не в 32 и не в 50?

Comment: @bone_appettit потому что в современном байте 8 бит, в 32-битных процессорах под число отводится 4 байта (32 бита), один бит уходит на обозначение знака плюс/минус, остаётся 2^31 на значение числа (если точнее, используется дополнительный код). (А вот почему в современном байте 8 бит, я не помню)

Answer (score 1):

Всё упирается в принципы передачи информации.

За раз мы можем передать только 1 бит информации, который принимает два (двойка в первой степени) значения - 0 и 1 для false и true соответственно.

За два раза мы можем передать 2 бита информации, которые принимают уже 4 (двойка во второй степени) значения - 00 01 10 11

За три раза мы можем передать 3 бита, которые принимают 8 (двойка в третьей степени) значений - 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111.

И так до бесконечности, пока не устанешь :)

Теперь по поводу числового типа данных int. Положительное количество принимаемых значений всегда меньше только потому что ноль тоже должен как-то кодироваться, и приходится жертвовать одним положительным числом